# Gaps in input but not in Id that I use as targets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wonder how I can do so that when someone writes the title of an album such as The Stage or the stage in the input, I'm going to the section with id thestage. Id can not have gaps so I must somehow first convert all capitals to small and also remove the space for it to match my id. Anyone have any good tips on how I can fix it?

```
<div class="ram" id="stage">
         <details>
           <summary>Click here to make a song selection!</summary>
           <a href="../AvengedSevenfold/stage/TheStage.html"><li>The Stage</li></a>
           <a href="../AvengedSevenfold/stage/Paradigm.html"><li>Paradigm</li></a>
           <a href="../AvengedSevenfold/stage/Sunny.html"><li>Sunny Disposition</li></a>
           <a href="../AvengedSevenfold/stage/Damn.html"><li>God Damn</li></a>
           <a href="../AvengedSevenfold/stage/creating.html"><li>Creating God</li></a>
           <a href="../AvengedSevenfold/stage/angels.html"><li>Angels</li></a>
           <a href="../AvengedSevenfold/stage/simulation.html"><li>Simulation</li></a>
           <a href="../AvengedSevenfold/stage/higher.html"><li>Higher</li></a>
           <a href="../AvengedSevenfold/stage/roman.html"><li>Roman Sky</li></a>
           <a href="../AvengedSevenfold/stage/fermi.html"><li>Fermi Paradox</li></a>
           <a href="../AvengedSevenfold/stage/exist.html"><li>Exist</li></a>
         </details>
        <img src="../bilder/The-Stage-Album-Cover-sept8_CMYK.jpg" alt="The Stage album">
       </div>

function main() {
  var $body = $("body").hide();
  $("body").fadeIn(1000);
  $('summary').each(function (){
    $(this).nextAll().wrapAll('<div class="slide"></div>');
  });
  $('details').attr('open','').find('.slide').css('display','none');
  $('summary').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).siblings('div.slide').slideToggle(function(){
  $(this).parent('details').toggleClass('open');});
  });
  }
$(document).ready(main);


function sendToPage() {
  var searched = $("#search").val().toLowerCase();
  console.log(searched)
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#" + searched).offset().top
  }, 1000);
}

function match(elem) {
  var validSearch = [
    "The Stage",
    "Hail to the King",
    "Nightmare",
    "Avenged Sevenfold",
    "City of Evil",
    "Waking the Fallen",
    "Sounding the Seventh Trumpet"];

  /** make search case insentive **/
  var searchKeys = [];
  for(c=0;c<validSearch.length;c++) {
    searchKeys[c] = validSearch[c].toLowerCase();
  }
  /** search the input **/
  var index = searchKeys.indexOf(elem.value.toLowerCase());

  /** if not matched **/
  if(index == -1) {
    window.alert("Album does not exist. Please try again");
  }
  else {
    var album = validSearch[index];
    window.alert("FOUND IT! " + album);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `match` function below has two main changes:

- The array searchKeys now has all the spaces removed, as well as lower case.
- It removes all spaces from the input string

Then it compares a lowercase string with no spaces with another lowercase string with no spaces.

```
function match(elem) {
  var validSearch = [
    "The Stage",
    "Hail to the King",
    "Nightmare",
    "Avenged Sevenfold",
    "City of Evil",
    "Waking the Fallen",
    "Sounding the Seventh Trumpet"];

  /** make search case insentive **/
  var searchKeys = [];
  for(c=0;c<validSearch.length;c++) {
    searchKeys[c] = validSearch[c].toLowerCase();
    // we also remove all spaces in the strings
    while (searchKeys[c].indexOf(' ') > -1) searchKeys[c] = searchKeys[c].replace(' ','');
  }
  /** search the input **/
  // remove all spaces from the search string
  searchString = elem.value.toLowerCase();
  while (searchString.indexOf(' ','') > -1) searchString = searchString.replace(' ','');
  var index = searchKeys.indexOf(searchString);

  /** if not matched **/
  if(index == -1) {
    window.alert("Album does not exist. Please try again");
  }
  else {
    var album = validSearch[index]; // Album full name
    var anchor = searchKeys[index]; // Album lowercase full name
    while (anchor.indexOf(' ')>-1) anchor = anchor.replace(' ',''); // we remove the spaces
    window.alert("FOUND IT! " + album + " will now scroll to " + anchor);
    window.location.href = '#'+anchor; // scroll to the given object
  }
}
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mcompte/7z28swtn/).

Comment: It doesn't work. When i type "night mare" in the input field this message appears "Album does not exist. Please try again"

Comment: In your example you indicated your problem was converting the album found into a way to scroll the page to your id (lowercase, no spaces), you didn't say your problem was also to find the album (ignoring the spaces). When posting a question, please specify clearly what is the answer you expect. To fix your problem you can remove all spaces from both the `elem` and the `validSearch`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! But that's what i meant with "I wonder how I can do so that when someone writes the title of an album such as The Stage or the stage in the input, I'm going to the section with id thestage."

Comment: `I must somehow first convert all capitals to small and also remove the space for it to match my id. Anyone have any good tips on how I can fix it?` That was the question, once the album has been found, how to remove the spaces so it finds the ID in your page. But it's ok, I added your new question in my answer.

Comment: I can't make it to work... Should it not be brackets after the while condition? :)

Comment: If it is only one line inside the while, you don't need brackets.

Comment: Do you have time to post your whole match function? So can i compare it to mine function and see what I doing wrong :)

Comment: I updated the answer. There was an error in my previous one. I tested this one in jsfiddle.

Comment: My smooth scroll with the function sendToPage has stopped to work now :)

Comment: I don't know what library are you using to do the smooth scroll. If you have an example on how to call the smooth scroll, just replace the `window.location.href = '#'+anchor` line with the call to your scrolling function.

Comment: $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#" + anchor).offset().top
    }, 1000); worked well! :)

Answer (score 0):

The following will convert "The Stage" or "the stage" to lower case and remove the white space:

```
var str = "The Stage";
var res = str.toLowerCase();
res  = res.replace(/\s/g, '');
```

Will give you: `thestage`